# Isdigit don't regonize Char * like digirt

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code , and im wondeing why my `char *bdin` didn't regonized to be digit , when it is checked in function isdigit()? Here is my improved getline and my check function, for check function dont look to argument, i just created function to experiment. I think when i put `bdin` in function `isdigit()`, it give them address to first element `[0]`. I try to do also with `(char *) (bdin)[0]` to get first element , because other is `'\n'` and `'\0'`, but it still don't workin...

```
int getline(char *ulaz)
{
    int i , c;
    for ( i = 0; (c = getchar())!= EOF && c!='\n';i++, ulaz++)
            *ulaz = c;

    if ( c =='\n')
    *ulaz++ = '\n';
        *ulaz = '\0';
    return i;
}

void checker(void)
{
    int duzina;
    char *bdin;
    duzina = getline(&bdin);
if ( isdigit(bdin))
    printf("It is digit!!\n");
    else
        printf("no!\n");
}
```

Comment: Whatever else might be wrong with this code, `isdigit(bdin)` should be `isdigit(*bdin)`

Comment: To begin with, change `char *bdin` to `char bdin`. Funny that the compiler didn't warn you about it.

Comment: @barakmanos: I just tried a similar example with gcc. It doesn't warn about it because `isdigit` is defined as a macro. It casts its argument to `int`; casting a pointer to `int` is legal and doesn't produce a warning. If you either `#undef isdigit` or replace the call by `(isdigit)(bdin)`, you invoke the actual function rather than the macro, and you'll get a compile-time diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behaviour because you did not allocate memory that would be pointed to by bdin and where you are going to write the input.
Also the program has other errors of using incorrect data types. Fpr example the type of expression

```
&bdin
```

is `char **` while the corresponding parameter of the function has type `char *`

Also this expression has no sense.

isdigit(bdin)

The type of the parameter of function isdigit is `int` while you pass `char *` You could write for example

```
if ( isdigit( *bdin ) )
```

or

```
if ( isdigit( bdin[0] ) )
```

but in any case the function will check only one character whether it is a digit or not.

Comment: Thank you man, can u tell me quick tips how to write code for getting line from funcition getline , and check , is that digit?

Comment: @lotoflaugh Do you want to check whether the first character of a string is a digit or that the string consists only from digits?

Comment: Sorry i didnt give u information about this, i want to check if that string is consisting only from digits. I want to check if that line is digit , does not matter if it is "1" or "23241". But if can you tell me process with using function getline... that will be the best solution for my exercise.

Comment: @lotoflaugh I think you should use an aray with fixed size and interrupt input when the array will be filled or when the new line character was entered.